# Th and td with different width on dsiplay block setted

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a table which `tbody` scrolls  but the `thead` is fixed
with this css

```
thead, tbody{
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

It works but the `th` witdh of  the `thead` is different of the rest of the columns of `td` it happens when I set `display: block;`.
I' ve tried with a lot of examples with the same result.

Comment: That's how tables work. When you make thead and tbody display:block, you put their child rows into separate anonymous tables, so they establish their cell widths independently. You have to explicitly set the widths of the cells and use table-layout:fixed to stop the layout automatically adjusting the cell widths.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned display : block only used for show option when you change as display : none; it has been hide you thead and tbody. That's the difference for display:block.

Comment: The problem its that the thead elements width is different than the tbody elements.

Comment: i assure the display element does not affect the width of thead and tbody.

if you have any doubts refer this URL:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: I know that display:block is not  to set width or similar,but the fact its if I set display block the cell size is different than is not setted